# How does the information in the problem statement and this solution align with the provided description of the method of moments?

Tags: method-of-moments

I have the following problem:

> Let $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ be i.i.d. $\text{Uniform}(\theta, 1)$ random variables, and let an estimator be $\hat{\theta} = \min\{ Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n \}$.
>
> You may find the following information useful when answering this question:
> Let $U_1, \dots, U_n$ be i.i.d. $\text{Uniform}(0, 1)$ random variables, and let $X = \min\{ U_1, \dots, U_n \}$, which has the density $f_X(x) = n(1 - x)^{n - 1}$.
> (i) The first two moments are given by $E[X] = \dfrac{1}{n + 1}$ and $E[X^2] = \dfrac{2}{(n + 1)(n + 2)}$.
> (ii) It is known that the random variable $X$ and $\dfrac{\hat{\theta} - \theta}{1 - \theta}$ have the same distribution. So this implies that $E[X] = E\left[ \dfrac{\hat{\theta} - \theta}{1 - \theta} \right]$ and $E[X^2] = E \left[ \dfrac{(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2}{(1 - \theta)^2} \right]$.
>
> Find the bias, variance, and MSE (mean squared error) of $\hat{\theta}$.

I am given the following description of the **method of moments**:

> The main idea is based on expressing the *population moments* of the distribution of data in terms of its unknown parameter(s) and equating them to their corresponding *sample moments*. The parameter(s) are then estimated by the solutions of the resulting equations.

The solution begins by calculating the first two moments of $\hat{\theta}$:

$$\begin{align} E \left[ \dfrac{ \hat{\theta} - \theta }{ 1 - \theta } \right] = E[X] = \dfrac{1}{n + 1} \Rightarrow E \left[ \hat{\theta} \right] = \dfrac{ n \theta + 1 }{ n + 1 } \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} E \left[ \left( \dfrac{\hat{\theta} - \theta }{ 1 - \theta } \right)^2 \right] = E \left[ X^2 \right] = \dfrac{2}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} &\Rightarrow \dfrac{ E\left[ \hat{\theta}^2 \right] - 2\theta E\left[ \hat{\theta} \right] + \theta^2 }{(1 - \theta)^2} = \dfrac{2}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} \\ &\Rightarrow E \left[ \hat{\theta}^2 \right] = \dfrac{n(n + 1) \theta^2 + 2n \theta + 2 }{ (n + 1)(n + 2) } \end{align}$$

How does the information in the problem statement, including (i) and (ii), and this solution align with the provided description of the method of moments? I'm a bit confused when trying to conceptually connect these two.

Comment: The method of moments wasn't used here; they simply equated equal equations and solved for $E[\hat \theta]$ and $E[\hat \theta^2]$ which will be needed to calculate bias, variance, and MSE.

Comment: @Stacker ahh, ok, that makes sense then. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of moments wasn't used here; the beginning of the solution just equates equal expressions together to find $E[\hat \theta]$ and $E[\hat \theta^2]$, which will be needed to find the bias, variance, and MSE.

The method of moments is used for estimating a parameter. In this situation it would be used to estimate the parameter $\theta$. Here we are given that $\hat \theta=\min \{Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n\}$. This is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ if the density is $f(y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-\theta}&\theta\le y\le 1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ because it maximizes the likelihood $f(\textbf y|\theta)=\frac{1}{(1-\theta)^n}\textbf 1_{\min {Y_1,...,Y_n}\ge\theta}$, as $f$ is an increasing function of $\theta$. However if $f(y)=\begin{cases}\frac 1{1-\theta}&\theta<y<1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ this would not be the maximum likelihood estimator (no MLE would exist, as $\theta<\min \textbf Y$ and so can be made arbitrarily close to it but cannot be made equal to $\min \textbf Y$) and would just be any unnamed estimator. The method of moments estimator would be $E(Y)=m_1$ with $m_1$ being the first moment. So we would get $\frac{1+\theta}{2}=\bar Y\Rightarrow \hat\theta=2\bar Y-1$ as the method of moments estimator. Another estimator is a Bayes estimator, but this requires placing a prior on $\theta$ and also specifying a loss function.